# slow query with joins

Tags: mysql, join

Please am having difficulty in optimizing this query. What am trying to achieve is to join about 8 tables, of which only about 3 of the tables contains large data (1.5m records). This query returns expected records but is taking 1min to run which is bad.
I know it can be optimized to perform far better, pls i need assistance from you experts. I have index on the fields used for join already.

```
SELECT topic_id, 
   topic_title, 
   unit_name_abbrev, 
   sch_name_abbrev, 
   picture_small_url    AS thumbnail, 
   profile_pix_upload_path, 
   first_name, 
   last_name, 
   topic_poster, 
   topic_replies, 
   topic_views, 
   topic_last_post_time AS topic_post_time, 
   sch_sub_forum_id 
FROM   (_sch_forum_topics 
    INNER JOIN _users 
            ON ( _users.userid = _sch_forum_topics.topic_poster ) 
    INNER JOIN _profile 
            ON _profile.userid = _users.userid 
    INNER JOIN _class 
            ON _users.classid = _class.classid 
    INNER JOIN _level 
            ON _class.level_id = _level.id 
    INNER JOIN _unit 
            ON _class.unitid = _unit.unitid 
    INNER JOIN _department 
            ON _unit.deptid = _department.deptid 
    INNER JOIN _faculty 
            ON _department.facid = _faculty.facid 
    INNER JOIN _university 
            ON _faculty.schid = _university.schid) 
WHERE  _sch_forum_topics.sch_sub_forum_id = 4 
ORDER  BY _sch_forum_topics.topic_last_post_time DESC 
LIMIT  0, 15
```

Comment: Try moving your inner joins outside on your  where clause and check your indices. Also, what does `EXPLAIN` on the query show?

Comment: Post an EXPLAIN output most likly it has many records to analyse and query is most likly to have an need for "Using temporary; Using filesort;" because the MySQL optimizer is cost based so it most likly access the wrong table order..

Comment: Remove the order by clause and see if the it is doing well, if yes place index on columns in order by clause

Comment: If this query is called by some backend script, then usually there is a different technique, namely caching the related objects and then retrieving them via id. Doing complex queries on DB realtime should better be avoided, they are almost guaranteed to be slow.

Comment: yes the performance improved when i removed the order by clause. But the field use by the clause is indexed already. It's a timestamp field

Comment: @NsikakEdet, please rollback my last change, I made disappear the image.

Comment: Does the `_sch_forum_topics table` have an index where the first (or only column) is `sch_sub_forum_id`? EXPLAIN is your friend. It will tell you where you are spinning your wheels. In general, establishing indexes on JOIN and WHERE columns will improve performance.

Comment: i have tried the code but still having issues

Comment: it has topic_id as the primary key and sch_sub_forum_id as an index too

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter before making JOIN's.

```
SELECT topic_id, 
   topic_title, 
   unit_name_abbrev, 
   sch_name_abbrev, 
   picture_small_url    AS thumbnail, 
   profile_pix_upload_path, 
   first_name, 
   last_name, 
   topic_poster, 
   topic_replies, 
   topic_views, 
   topic_last_post_time AS topic_post_time, 
   sch_sub_forum_id
FROM
 ( select  * FROM  sch_forum_topics WHERE sch_sub_forum_id = 4
ORDER BY topic_last_post_time DESC 
LIMIT  0, 15 ) main
    INNER JOIN _users 
            ON ( _users.userid = main.topic_poster ) 
    INNER JOIN _profile 
            ON _profile.userid = _users.userid 
    INNER JOIN _class 
            ON _users.classid = _class.classid 
    INNER JOIN _level 
            ON _class.level_id = _level.id 
    INNER JOIN _unit 
            ON _class.unitid = _unit.unitid 
    INNER JOIN _department 
            ON _unit.deptid = _department.deptid 
    INNER JOIN _faculty 
            ON _department.facid = _faculty.facid 
    INNER JOIN _university 
            ON _faculty.schid = _university.schid);
```

Comment: this query is not equivalent to the original one.

Comment: I believe the limit you apply prior to joining is not the same as doing so afterwards.

Comment: True, I had to order as well, because of the limit. Now that I did it, there should be no difference with the original query.

Comment: there was no error except for the slowness of the query. the query is still very slow

Comment: could you run explain on this query and post the output?